# Different window size to OpenGL back buffer size on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl

Currently the only option I can find is to blit to the back buffer from a differently sized frame buffer just before performing a swap. This option is simple, but comes with a few complications of it's own that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Apple provide a [CGL API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_contexts/opengl_contexts.html) called `kCGLCPSurfaceBackingSize` that provides this functionality. Maybe one of Xorg, SDL, GLFW, SFML, etc. provide this, but I can't currently find the functionality.

Does anyone know of a function similar to the Apple API that is available for Linux?

Comment: That is a feature of CGL, not one of GL or X or they others. This probably works because the compositor is sampling from the applications output texture in any case, so an additional scale is virtually free. In principle, such things can be done with any compositor, but I'm not aware of any API for that on the linux compositiors.